# gnuplot Qt5 install FAIL

Tags: qt5, gnuplot

I'm running 20.04 but after several tries I can not get gunplot to install properly wiht qt5. I followed the  instructions from another Q/A:

```
sudo apt install qtbase5-dev qtbase5-dev-tools libqt5svg5-dev qttools5-dev-tools 
cd ~ 
wget https://jaist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/gnuplot/gnuplot/5.4.1/gnuplot-5.4.1.tar.gz 
tar -xvzf gnuplot-5.4.1.tar.gz 
cd gnuplot-5.4.1 
./configure --with-qt=qt5 
make -j # uses more jobs for faster compiling and linking 
make check    # make a test before installing
```

But when running 'make check' if get pages of this (the formatting is wacky, but the text is correct):

```
Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-xcomposite-glx") QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata= { "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3", "MetaData": { "Keys": [ "xcb" ] }, "archreq": 0, "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin", "debug": false, "version": 330752 }
Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb") QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/dad/Downloads/gnuplot-5.4.1/src/platforms" ... loaded library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so" Failed to create wl_display (No such file or directory) Using Wayland-EGL failed to initialize EGL display qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "wayland-egl" in "" even though it was found. This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
Warning: slow font initialization Warning: slow font initialization Warning: slow font initialization Warning: slow font initialization Warning: slow font initializationHit return to continue
```

I get blocks of the above text, one for each type of window e.g. wayland-egl.
It seems to me that the Qt5 in not installed properly, but I have installed, and re-installed a few times, but still get the above errors. Help.

Comment: Simple : `sudo apt install gnuplot-qt`  https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gnuplot-qt

Comment: Ubuntu  20.04 : A test build with gnuplot-5.4.1 : No issues, see gnuplot_TextFile https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1d48PCFP-gGO1VTXgnvDq0CXmsnFtUpHe?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: Knud Larsen your suggested commands worked, except I could not get gnuplot 5.4.1++dfsg1-1. Instead I used: apt-get -b source gnuplot=5.2.8+dfsg1-1 That seemed to install correctly. I do not get any errors making my plots now - Thanx.